# Windows commands not working in reverse shell

Tags: shell, reverse

I used many reverse shells to connect to a windows machine. nc connects to it, but as soon as I write a command and press enter, it blocks and stops working. No output is returned.
When I use meterpreter commands I can navigate in the system, but once I use the "shell" command and use a windows command (example. dir, or whoami) it asks me if I want to exit the channel. The machine is a windows 2012 r2 (6.3 build 9600)